# Reset EV with Secret Training?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I have a few Pokemon at 80 that I didn't EV train. I hear Super Training or Super Secret Training can reset EV for Pokemon at "any" level.

How can I redo my EV points for Pokemon at high levels? And how will EV points restart if you're already at say max level?

No matter what I try, it tells me `"x's base stats can't go higher! It can't use the HP Bag M!"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just hit the default punching bag in Super Training and you'll be given random punching bags (up to a max of 12; throw away extra bags at this point, or use them up). Somewhat rarely you will be given an unmarked white bag called a reset bag which totally resets EVs. I've heard rumors that pokemon with 0 Evs are more likely to give out reset bags, but in my experience pokemon with full EVs at the least still CAN give EV bags.

The EV reset is complete and level doesn't matter. Then you can just use Super Training to perfectly train your pokemon.

Comment: I tried this and just used a Reset Bag, but after it still tells me "x's base stats can't go higher! It can't use the HP Bag M!"

Comment: @Zeno It used the reset bag and destroyed it? What does the EV chart say?

Comment: Yes. What chart is that?

Comment: @Zeno the big chat on the Super Training page that shows  the EVs as a hexagonal graph

Comment: Even if you reset the EVs, if the pokemon is level 80 they only have 20 levels of stat gain left. With max EVs, will this result in the same gain as if you'd raised a level 1 with max EVs?

Comment: @Jason_c_o you can add EVs at any time

Comment: @BenBrocka that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Your EVs will affect your stats **immediately**. For example, say your Lv80 has an attack stat of 200, with 0 Atk EVs. You fully EV train it in Atk. Look at its summary page and you'll see its attack stat has grown considerably. This is a change from Generation IV and older where stat changes would only occur on level-up (making it impossible to EV train a Lv100 Pokémon, as it cannot level up), but even in those games your 'new' EVs are applied immediately on level-up.

Comment: @Kai Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't aware that it had changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to the Juice Shoppe in Lumiose City to either buy or mix up a juice that would reset a pokemon's EVs.

It's called the Perilous Soup, and it's created by mixing the Kee Berry and the Maranga Berry together. Be careful though, you can only mix once per day.

Getting those berries are pretty difficult with conventional methods because of the new mechanic of interbreeding berries, so see if you can get them off of trades and plant those berries instead of going through a bunch of tedious steps to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a reset bag on the core training